# rsync /data/*/images/ pattern

Tags: rsync

I have a folder structure as follows:

```
- data
-- user 1
--- images
--- other stuff
-- user 2
--- images
--- other stuff
-- user 3
...
```

I want to `rsync` all `images` folders. If I am using a include/exclude rule, I run into trouble, since I do not know the user `id` up front. In the real application it is a random number.

I need something like this `data/**/images/`, meaning take all image folders beneath the data folder.

Is this feasible without cheating like piping `ls` or similar into `rsync`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to copy all the `images` folders then a simple shell wildcard would be sufficient. However, you seem to want to keep the paths on the destination so you'll need the `-R` flag to do that.

```
cd /path/to/data
rsync -iavR */images remote:/path/to/destination/
```

This will include the `*/images` part of the source path on the destination underneath the target directory. So if you had `/path/to/data/12345/images/picnic.jpg` on the source you would end up with that being copied to `/path/to/destination/12345/images/picnic.jpg`

Add `--progress` or `--dry-run` if you're running interactively and want to see what's going on.